# Hidden characters in Oracle SELECT query

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry if the question sounds basic, but I was unable to find the cause of it.

I have an oracle procedure in which a SOAP webservice with parameters is invoked.

When I hardcode the parameters in the webservice and compile and execute the procedure, I get a 200 OK response. Also when I manually pass parameters as IN parameter to the procedure and use the variable storing it in the webservice, I still get a 200 OK response.

But issues arise when I use a select query inside the procedure to retrieve the parameters from a database table, store it in variables defined in the procedure, and then use these variables in the webservice. The webservice fails and I get a 500 error indicating non-valid parameters.

My first reaction was regarding whitespace characters in the query results and hence I used the TRIM() function for each query field. But I again get a 500 error response.

WORKING:

```
< authentication >  
< username >abcde< /username >  
< password >abcde< /password >  
< /authentication>
```

NON-WORKING:

```
var_user VARCHAR2(10);  
var_pass VARCHAR2(10);

< authentication >  
< username >'||var_user||'< /username >  
< password >'||var_pass||'< /password>  
< /authentication>

select TRIM(username),TRIM(password) into var_user,var_pass from TBL_USER  where.....;
```

Any help or pointers on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps `DUMP` function can be useful to debug this issue: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions048.htm#SQLRF00635 Dump values selected by the query to the log, and examine them.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is caused by whitespaces, could be return or any invisible characters (/n, /r...). I'd use a regular expression function to remove unwanted characters. 
here is an example, it will remove tab and space.

```
select 'asdfo'||chr(9)||'dsu iue', regexp_replace('asdfo'||chr(9)||'dsu iue', '['||chr(9)||' ]','') from dual
```

Or this will remove all control characters

```
select 'asdfo'||chr(9)||'dsu iue', regexp_replace('asdfo'||chr(9)||'dsu iue', '[[:cntrl:] ]','') from dual
```